# pdf2htmlEX on Debian 10 for use with Drupal

Tags: debian-jessie, debian-buster, pdf2htmlex

There's a server migration going on, and they're moving from a Debian 8 to a Debian 10.
Everything works great except for pdf2htmlEX. The old server used v0.14.6, to which I tried to compile without success. Using the jessie package results in dependency issues, and those packages are too old and have been replaced.

I've tried with 0.18.7 and 0.16.0 (all version can be [found on GitHub](https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX/releases)), and so far 0.18.7 seems to be the one working best, although some conversions result in white or transparent text (made an issue [here](https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX/issues/60)).

As for 0.18.7, you need to compile poppler-0.81.0. I used [this guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/poppler.html) which uses 0.89.0 as an example. Compiles without error.

Is there something I am missing? `fontforge` is already the newest version.

Any help is very much appreciated.